# Why does Mongoose hide my field?

Tags: mongoose

Mongoose seems to be hiding my timestamp field when I'm setting it in a pre 'save' hook. Any idea why?

I have this Schema:

```
var dpsSchema = new Schema({
    timestamp: Date,
    _loaded_schedules: [{type: Number, ref: 'prun_schedules'}]
})

dpsSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    this.timestamp = new Date();
    next();
})
```

and I run this code:

```
var Dpm_model = mongoose.model('daily_production_meta', dpm_schema);

var pm = new Dpm_model();
pm.save();

setTimeout(console.log(pm), 2000);
```

The resulting console log looks like this:

```
{ _id: 5871410c08b91cfd82124656,
  _loaded_schedules: [] }
```

But when I log into mongodb via terminal and check that document, I see the timestamp field!

How come?

Comment: The `.save()` runs asynchronous, so maybe the 2 seconds aren't enough. Try `.save().then(doc => console.log(doc);` May I ask why you use this timestamp? In case you want to save when the document was created or modiefied, there is a build-in option for this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your call to

```
pm.save();
```

This is an async call, expecting a callback.

Change this to

```
pm.save(function(err){ 
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(pm)}, 2000);
});
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: I'd like to add that setTimeout actually seems to require something along the lines of `setTimeout(function(){console.log(pm)}, 2000);` for it to work without using the promise.